# How To Create a Vertical SeekBar in Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am using Xamarin Free Version and I am trying to Create a Seek Bar the following

The Seek bar will be white with a white thumb and the golden box next to it is content

Link to image:
  http://s8.postimg.org/gpt6ao5xh/Veritcal_Seek_Bar.jpg

The only thing is that there will be 6 SeekBars in a row down in that format

All the examples are for horizontal seek bars and not much for vertical

the current way I am doing it is by using

```
android:Rotation="270"
```

which does make it vertical but i cant achieve the format above and everything is funny

does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use rotation on the top layout like in the following code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="260dp"
    android:rotation="270">

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:progress="50" />

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:progress="70" />

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:progress="50" />

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:progress="20" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Another solution would be to use a custom VerticalSeekBar (same rotation concept), like [AndroSelva, Vertical-SeekBar-Android](https://github.com/AndroSelva/Vertical-SeekBar-Android/blob/master/sample/src/android/widget/VerticalSeekBar.java) implementation

```
<android.widget.VerticalSeekBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="260dip" />
```

Or have your own real vertical seekbar implementation.

.

---

Check out my latest library project at https://github.com/MostafaGazar/CircularImageView-Xamarin-